# Symbian C++ and QT libs tohether under Series 3 SDK (Nokia N8)? is it possible?

Tags: qt, symbian, qt-creator, nokia

before posting this quesiton i did extensive research on Forum nokia, Stackoverflow and developer.symbian.org but still unable to find solution to the problem

I am building an application that uses Symbian C++ (to get advanced network data which QT cant provide) and QT libs (for user interface and xml saving and so many other things). Now here is the problem, i cannot build and run Symbian Series 3 sdk (0.9 and o.8) with QT Designer nor Carbide C++. if i use the same approach with Series 60 5th edition, it works like a charm but combining both Symbian C++ and QT (tried 4.6 and 4.7) targeting N8, i am unable to do so.

1:Can someone advise about how to setup the environment in which we can blend Symbian and QT together.

2:Can someone help me in writing down the instuctions from point 1 (i,e pre requisites) and then running a sample code.

This thing is going on my nerves, i will really appreciate your help Stackoverflow!!

Comment: Though I've not tried Symbian^3 0.9 SDK, the 0.8 one seems to be quite buggy. At least, I was unable to build my projects with it with the first attempt. Nevertheless, the native Symbian and Qt code should be mixed easily, so please post the exact problem you have, and I'll try to help you.

Answer (score 2):

Is there any reason you need to build on the Symbian^3 SDK? A build for S60 5th will work on the N8, so unless you need APIs specific to Symbian^3, why not stick with the S60 5th SDK?
(I've had similar problems with the S^3 SDK, but now work with 5th without a hitch)

Comment: thanks mate! i used the S60 5th edition and set the target terminal as N8 :D